# (One table) get rows not in without union

Tags: sql, postgresql

Sorry for the title I just do not know how to explain what I want to achieve briefly. But it is actually simple.

I have the following table `egr`:

```
+---------+------------+
|  offid  |  groupid   |
+---------+------------+
|       1 | 101        |
|       1 | 202        |
|       2 | 202        |
|       2 | 404        |
+---------+------------+
```

I would like to get the rows for which a groupid is not linked to the other offid. Result would be:

```
+---------+------------+
|  offid  |  groupid   |
+---------+------------+
|       1 | 101        |
|       2 | 404        |
+---------+------------+
```

This works but I was wondering if there was a more elegant way to do it?

```sql
select * from egr as egr1
where egr1.offid = 1
and egr1.groupid not in (select groupid from egr as egr2 where egr2.offid = 2 and egr1.groupid = egr2.groupid)
union
select * from egr as egr1
where egr1.offid = 2
and egr1.groupid not in (select groupid from egr as egr2 where egr2.offid = 1 and egr1.groupid = egr2.groupid)
```

In case you would like to try:

```sql
create table egr (offid int, groupid int);
insert into egr values (1, 101), (1, 202), (2, 202), (2, 404);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select e.*
from egr e
where not exists (select 1
                  from egr e2
                  where e2.groupid = e.groupid and e2.offid <> e.offid 
                 );
```

Or if you want to limit to just those two offers:

```
select e.*
from egr e
where e.offid in (1, 2) and
      not exists (select 1
                  from egr e2
                  where e2.groupid = e.groupid and 
                        e2.offid in (1, 2) and
                        e2.offid <> e.offid 
                 );
```

Comment: What would be the insert statement for inserting the groupid that the offid 1 is missing (but which offid 2 has)? Basically to add values (1, 404)

Comment: @StephaneB. . . . That is a different question and should be asked as a *new* question.

Answer (score 1):

Use `count()..over()`.

```
select groupid,offid
from (select groupid,offid,count(*) over(partition by groupid) as cnt
      from tbl
     ) t
where cnt = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```
select groupid from egr group by groupid having count(distinct offid) =1
```