# (One table) insert rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert, insert-select

This question is the continuation of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56246041/one-table-get-rows-not-in-without-union).

I have the following table `egr`:

```
+---------+------------+
|  offid  |  groupid   |
+---------+------------+
|       1 | 101        |
|       1 | 202        |
|       2 | 202        |
|       2 | 404        |
+---------+------------+
```

I would like to insert missing groupids that the offid 2 does not have (compared to offid 1). Result would be:

```
+---------+------------+
|  offid  |  groupid   |
+---------+------------+
|       1 | 101        |
|       1 | 202        |
|       2 | 202        |
|       2 | 404        |
|       2 | 101        |   --> new row to insert
+---------+------------+
```

My try, based on the answer of my other question (not working):

```sql
INSERT INTO egr (offid, groupid)
  SELECT 2, egr1.groupid
  FROM egr AS egr1 
  WHERE egr1.offid = 1
  AND NOT EXISTS
    (select 1
                  from egr e2
                  where e2.groupid = egr1.groupid and 
                        e2.offid in (1, 2) and
                        e2.offid <> egr1.offid 
                 );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be easier to achieve using the `except` operator:

```
INSERT INTO egr (offid, groupid)
SELECT 2, groupid
FROM   egr
WHERE  offid = 1
EXCEPT
SELECT 2, groupid
FROM   egr
WHERE  offid = 2
```

Comment: Yes this works: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=7acea85a9ab1fecdf401f7d6f7eb89a8 (in your SQL fiddle as well: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ef3f0/3) Although I would leave out the `WHERE offid = 1`part because you might have more than 2 values in reality.

Comment: @S-Man the OP's requirement was to insert to `offid=2` the values that `offid=1` has and it hasn't. If you omit that from the where clause, you may insert values from `offid='something else'`