# (One table) Insert rows with Sequence

Tags: sql, postgresql

This question is the continuation of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56250022/one-table-insert-rows).

I have the following table `egr`:

```
+---------+---------+------------+
|  egrid  |  offid  |  groupid   |
+---------+---------+------------+
|    1000 |       1 | 101        |
|    1001 |       1 | 202        |
|    1002 |       2 | 202        |
|    1003 |       2 | 404        |
+---------+---------+------------+
```

Note that `egrid` is a sequence.

I would like to insert missing groupids that the offid 2 does not have (compared to offid 1). Result would be:

```
+---------+---------+------------+
|  egrid  |  offid  |  groupid   |
+---------+---------+------------+
|    1000 |       1 | 101        |
|    1001 |       1 | 202        |
|    1002 |       2 | 202        |
|    1003 |       2 | 404        |
|    1004 |       2 | 101        |   --> new row to insert
+---------+---------+------------+
```

My try below, based on the answer of my other question (not working).
The problem I have is that the sequence is incremented with the select statement. But if there are 555 rows with offid = 1, it will be incremented 555 times although in the end, only a few will be inserted. I am looking for a nicer way to do it.

```sql
INSERT INTO egr (egrid, offid, groupid)
  SELECT nextval('seq_egrid'), 2, groupid
    FROM egr
    WHERE offid = 1
  EXCEPT
  SELECT egrid, 2, groupid
    FROM egr
    WHERE offid = 2
ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To only increment `nextval` in the cases where rows are added you could try something like this:

```
INSERT INTO egr (egrid, offid, groupid)
  SELECT nextval('seq_egrid'), 2, g FROM (
    SELECT groupid as g
      FROM egr
      WHERE offid = 1
    EXCEPT
    SELECT groupid
      FROM egr
      WHERE offid = 2
  ) AS t
ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
```

Comment: Modifying the schema is not an option unfortunately.

Comment: @StephaneB. does something like this help?

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the rows using:

```
select o.offid, g.groupid
from (select distinct offid from egr) as o cross join
     (select groupid from egr where offid = 1) g left join
     egr
     on egr.offid = o.offid and
        egr.groupid = g.groupid
where egr.offid is null;
```

I would not use a sequence for the first column, just a `serial` value, so I would write:

```
insert into egr (offid, groupid)
    select o.offid, g.groupid
    from (select distinct offid from egr) as o cross join
         (select groupid from egr where offid = 1) g left join
         egr
         on egr.offid = o.offid and
            egr.groupid = g.groupid
    where egr.offid is null;
```

And let the database assign the first value.  Of course, if you use using a sequence, you can be explicit:

```
insert into egr (egrid, offid, groupid)
    select nextval('seq_egrid'), o.offid, g.groupid
    from (select distinct offid from egr) as o cross join
         (select groupid from egr where offid = 1) g left join
         egr
         on egr.offid = o.offid and
            egr.groupid = g.groupid
    where egr.offid is null;
```